# Upload Photo in node js with monogodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

How to upload image in node js

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGpw7.png

I am trying to upload aa photo and save it on my database but its not working

How i upload the photo in database with node js

Comment: can you share.. what error you are getting while uploading the image ?

Comment: see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) as bellow :

```
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");


// Filter image type
function fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
 const allowed = ["image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"];

 if (!allowed.includes(file.mimetype)) {
   return cb("Type Error. Alowed types: png, jpg, jpeg", false);

 } else {
   return cb(undefined, true);
 }
}


// Set multer Storage Settings
const storage = multer.diskStorage({

 // File Destination
 destination(req, file, cb) {
   const uploadPath = path.join("uploads", "categories");

   if (!fs.existsSync(uploadPath)) {
     // if uploda directory not exists, will be create
     fs.mkdirSync(path.join(uploadPath), { recursive: true });
   }
   cb(undefined, uploadPath);
 },

 // File Name
 filename(req, file, cb) {
   // Current Time in milliseconds + file extension
   const fileName = `${new Date().getTime()}_${file.originalname.split('.')[0]}.${file.mimetype.split("/")[1]}`;
   return cb(undefined, fileName);
 }
});

// File size Limit
const limits = {
 fileSize: 11000000 // 11MB
};



const upload = multer({
 limits,
 storage,
 fileFilter
}).fields([{ name: "image", maxCount: 1 }]);



/**
* @description Add Product File Handler
*/
export default (req, res, next) => {
 upload(req, res, (err) => {
   if (err) {

     if (err === "Type Error. Alowed types: png, jpg, jpeg")
       return res.status(400).send({ msg: err, success: false });

     if (err.message)
       return res.status(400).send({ msg: err.message, success: false });


     return res.status(500).send({ msg: "server error.", success: false });
   }
   next();
 });
};
```

and the DB model (for example MongoDB):

```
    import mongoose from "mongoose"


const Image: mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    url: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    alt: {
        type: String,
    },
    meta: {
        type: String,
    }
    
}, { timestamps: true })


export default mongoose.model('Image', Image)
```

you can use Postman to test.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "multer" (npm package) to save photo on the same server which you are using to host your node.js application and save the link to that image as text in mongodb. You can find the documentation on "multer" on https://github.com/expressjs/multer.